# Find out if field is of type Currency without consuming Describe's?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits, describesobject, currency

Parts of my code copy hundreds of arbitrary fields of an arbitrary object to another object. Before copying currency fields I want to do some fx conversion.

How can I find out if a field is a currency field without consuming Describe calls. I am quite sure I would soon run into the 100 limit.

Any clever idea how to recognize currencies by value or any other means?

Comment: If you have less than 100 Decimal fields on any object you could use "instanceof Decimal" on the SObject.get result to filter out other type fields and cache the describe information as you go. My only other thought is to run a Batchable that creates list custom setting entries (for 100 fields or less per batch) that represent the information that your copy logic can then use (assuming the arbitrary fields are not constantly being added).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limits on describes are very confusingly written, you're not actually limited to 100 calls to Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe(), instead you're limited to 100 calls to Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().

This means that if you have a compile-time reference to the fields instead of using the more dynamic fields.getMap() you won't use *any* describe limits.

The limit being on fields.getMap() really means that you can't enumerate fields on more than 100 SObject types in a single transaction. If you use some form of caching ([I have an open source example](https://github.com/capeterson/Apex-Util/blob/master/src/classes/SObjectDescribe.cls)) this is a pretty generous limit.

I actually had to defend this assertion on a code review recently, here's some anonymous apex that can experimentally demonstrate this:

```
List<Schema.SObjectType> objects = new List<Schema.SObjectType>{ Account.SObjectType, Contact.SObjectType, Case.SObjectType, User.SObjectType, Lead.SObjectType};
Integer describes = 0;
while(describes < 500){
    for(Schema.SObjectType objType: objects){
        for(Schema.SObjectField fld: objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
            describes++;
            System.debug('Ran describe ob '+fld.getDescribe().getName());
        }
    }
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Ran a total of '+describes+'field describes');
```

In my test org, with a handful of custom fields, that gets up to 790 calls to Schema.SObjectField.getDescribe() without any issue.